# Twig impossible to invoke a method on a string variable

Tags: symfony, twig

After updating `"twig/twig"` to `"v2.4.4"` I have an error when calling macro function.

```
Impossible to invoke a method ("widget_prototype") on a string variable (":ERP/timesheets:_form_part.html.twig").
```

My macro:

```
{% macro widget_prototype(widget, remove_text) %}
{% if widget.vars.prototype is defined %}
    {% set form = widget.vars.prototype %}
    {% set name = widget.vars.prototype.vars.name %}
{% else %}
    {% set form = widget %}
    {% set name = widget.vars.full_name %}
{% endif %}
```

Calling macro part:

```
{% include ':ERP/timesheets:_data_content_supply_from_widget.html.twig' with {form:form, name:name} %}

{% endmacro %}

            <div id="post_supplies"
             data-prototype="{{ _self.widget_prototype(form.supplies, 'remove'|trans({}, 'common'))|escape }}"
             style="margin-bottom: 5px">
            {% for widget in form.supplies.children %}
                {{ _self.widget_prototype(widget, 'remove'|trans({}, 'common')) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

How to correctly call macro? Tried calling without `_self` and I have the error: `Unknown "widget_prototype" function.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the macro, not include it

```
{% import "my_macro.twig" as my_macro %}
{{ my_macro.function(arg1) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

DarkBee's answer is good, but if your macro is in the same twig file that's calling it then you will *still* need to import it like so:

```
{% import _self as my_macros %}
{{ my_macros.widget_prototype(...) }}
```

Seems a bit counter-intuitive but that's how it is.