# Symfony Twig Error: Unknown "^macro_name^" function. Did you mean "^similar_function_name^"?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I have made the following twig extention:

```
class MyExtentions extends \Twig_Extension
{
   public function getFunctions()
   {
       return array(
           new \Twig_SimpleFunction('simiral_function_name', array($this, 'someFunction'),array('needs_environment' => true)),
       );
   }


   public function someFunction($url)
   {
       $url=parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH);
       $url=explode('/',$url);

       $params="";

       foreach($item as $key=> $url){
           $params.="_".$item;
       }

       return $params;
   }
}
```

And over my Twig Template I did the following macro:

```
{% macro macro_name(url) %}
    {{ path('route_name',{'chunk':simiral_function_name(url)}) }}
{% endmacro   macro_name %}
```

But when over my template I access it eg:

```
<a href="{{macro_name("http://example.com/path/files/somefile")}}"></a>
```

I get the following error:

```
Unknown "macro_name" function. Did you mean "similar_function_name"?
```

Comment: [import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47014154/446594) the macro first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just when you want to use the template do as described [there](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html):

```
{% import _self as macro_template %}
```

Afterwards you can use it as:

```
<a href="{{macro_template.macro_name("http://example.com/path/files/somefile")}}"></a>
```

In place of `macro_template` you can put whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

instead of {% endmacro  article_route %} change to  {% endmacro macro_name %}

```
{% macro macro_name(url) %}
    {{ path('route_name',{'chunk':simiral_function_name(url)}) }}
{% endmacro macro_name %}
```

more details [Named Macro End-Tags](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html#named-macro-end-tags)